# Instatiating a prefab around another prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
private void ContinueToSpawn()
{
        normalBlockPool[0].transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(minInsOffsetX,  maxInsOffsetX), currentBlockY);
        currentBlockY += Random.Range(minDisBetweenBlocks, maxDisBetweenBlocks);

        if(player.transform.position.y > 150 && Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.1f)
        {
            SlimeSpawner();
        }
        else if(player.transform.position.y > 50 && Random.Range(0,2) < 0.5f)
        {
            isBrokenPlatform = true;
            BrokenPlatformSpawner();

            if(isBrokenPlatform)
            {
                Vector2 blockPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(minInsOffsetX, maxInsOffsetX), currentBlockY);
                GameObject gO = Instantiate(grassPlatformPrefab, blockPos, Quaternion.identity);
                gO.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = grassSpriteList[grassSpriteCount];
                gO.transform.SetParent(transform);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            GrassSpawner();
        }
        GameObject temp = normalBlockPool[0];
        normalBlockPool.RemoveAt(0);
        normalBlockPool.Add(temp); 
    }
```

My intention is to instantiate grass platform prefab below 0y to 5y range of my broken platform when it is instantiated. However this code instantiate grass platform at the beginning of the game (1y or 2y). What changes should I make so I can instantiate grass platform randomly at that desired position range?⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: The `unityscript` tag has been deprecated [like the language itself](https://blog.unity.com/community/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset). If you are asking a unity related question, use the `unity3d` tag instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
Vector2 blockPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(minInsOffsetX, maxInsOffsetX), currentBlockY);
```

which is a random position around world `0,0,0` you rather want to add this to an existing position like e.g.

```
Vector2 blockPos = new Vector2(referencePositionX + Random.Range(minInsOffsetX, maxInsOffsetX), currentBlockY);
```

Note btw that

```
Random.Range(0,2) < 0.5f
```

is a bit odd. Note that `Random.Range(0, 2)` has exactly two possible values `0` or `1` (for `int` the upper bound is exclusive) so you could as well use

```
Random.Range(0,2) == 0
```

or if your intention was to use float it needs to be

```
Random.Range(0f,2f) < 0.5f
```

Comment: Is that so simple! Thank you so much Mr. derHugo. It worked.